# Splitting a hyphen delimited string with negative numbers or range of numbers

Tags: javascript

Problem:

--

Input:
"ABC-PQR--1-XYZ"

Expected Output:
['ABC', 'PQR', '-1', 'XYZ']

--

Input:
"ABC-PQR-7-15-XYZ"

Expected Output:
['ABC', 'PQR', '7-15', 'XYZ']

--

I tried using lookback and lookahead regex. Getting confused. Any pointers?

```
.split(/(?<=\d)-/);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ye5ojhcs/4/

Comment: Examples are good, but what are your rules when the string is different? Think of "A92-5+8/2-4X-5--9", ...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/-(?=[A-Za-z-]|\d+-\d)/
```

```js
const str = "ABC-PQR--1-APAC";
const str2 = "ABC-PQR-7-15-XYZ";

const pattern = /-(?=[A-Za-z-]|\d+-\d)/;

const splitt = str.split(pattern);
const splitt2 = str2.split(pattern);

console.log(splitt, splitt2);
```

Comment: thanks, this does work for a negative number, but not for the range of numbers

Comment: Keep in mind - Safari 13.1.1 still not supports lookbehind ?<= , so there you'll get `Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`

Comment: Thank you @tarkh that is an unfortunate restriction. I've updated my answer again to get around this.

Comment: Why do you pass a regex literal to `RegExp`?

Comment: @trincot Why not? It prevents having to escape the backslashes in a string

Comment: Why? A regex literal is *already* a regex... No need to pass it to `RegExp`.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could match the wanted parts by looking for

- a range
- a negative number
- not minus characters

```js
const split = string => string.match(/\d+-\d+|(?<=-)-\d+|[^-]+/g)

console.log(split("ABC-PQR--1-XYZ"));
console.log(split("ABC-PQR-7-15-XYZ"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Keep in mind - Safari 13.1.1 still not supports lookbehind ?<= , so there you'll get `Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name`

Answer (score 1):

Also this is the simple approach with simple logic:

```js
let str = 'ABC-PQR-7-15-XYZ--3-HH';

// Replace digit groups and minus
str = str.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)/g, '$1<minus>$2');
str = str.replace(/--/g, '-<minus>');

// Split
let arr = str.split('-');

// Replace markers back
arr = arr.map(val => val = val.replace(/<minus>/, '-'));

// Log
console.log(arr);
```